# How can I synchronous two databases

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization

I have two databases. First one is local and the other is at Internet, in my domain. I want to synchronous two databases. Is it possible to do so ? How can I synchronous two databases ?

Some detailed note on the databases, master databases is the local one, I wish to update Internet database from local one so that even Internet goes down, my databases reside in the my domain would be available.

To update the databases, I am mostly using the MySQL.

Visualization :

I mainly work on the local database.

```
      |-----|                   |-----|
      |     |                   |     | 
      |     |  <---->           |     |
      |-----|                   |-----|
       local                     database at my domain

               synchronization
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Replication

"Replication enables data from one MySQL database server (the master) to be replicated to one or more MySQL database servers (the slaves)"

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

Comment: If I use sqlite in the local one. Still, can replication be used?

Comment: @slaki - you, you cannot replicate between sqlite and mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Try [greplicator](http://www.ywsystems.com/?page_id=11)

greplicator is indeed a-time solution made to replicate data from MySQL database holiday to a relational database, for example Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, IBM DB2 UDB and MySQL